# Link not working till deployment completes in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have 2 web applications(say A and B) hosted on tomcat via their corresponding war files.

And at runtime, I'm using "A" to change the contents of "B" and then moving the new war file of "B" in tomcat web-apps, also at runtime. This triggers the redeployment of "B" by tomcat.

Now I'm having a link at some webpage in "A" from which I'm trying to open the application "B".

But the problem I'm facing is that the link does not work till the deployment of "B" is completed.
Also the deployment time varies accordingly.

So how can this situation be handled?

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on [`autoDeploy`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment) and simply move the `.war` file to the `webapps` folder, the polling of that folder can take up to 20 seconds (by default) to see the change.

Don't use that mechanism, but upload the war through the Tomcat [`manager`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html) webapp, because that instantly triggers the deployment, and you get the response when the deployment is complete.

Comment: @Nobita You send an HTTP request with the command, or you use JMX. Time to read the documentation I linked to.